# Wordpress shortcode displaying

Tags: php, html, wordpress, shortcode

I inputed shortcode in post in WordPress panel. And I want to display custom HTML code which I inputed in `single.php`, for example when this shortcode is activated. I tried this code, but it doesn't work.

```
<?php 
    if ( shortcode_exists( 'secondfloor' ) ) { 
        echo '<h2>Mytag</h2>';
} ?>
```

Comment: can you add whole code that you have created shortcode for secondfloor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this code:

```
if ( !shortcode_exists( 'hello_world' ) ) {
    add_shortcode('hello_world', 'hello_world');
    function hello_world() {
       $html = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.';
      return $html;
    }
}
```

**Use in editor:**

```
[hello_world]
```

**Use in PHP file:**

```
echo do_shortcode('[hello_world]');
```